# IBM Worklight - How to bypass WP's " Unable to add dynamic content" warning?

Tags: sencha-touch, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst

I have tried to run a Windows Phone 8 App written in Sencha Touch in Worklight. I used sencha in the following way:

```
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script><script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script><script>
    // Define WL namespace.
    var WL = WL ? WL : {};
    /**
     * WLClient configuration variables.
     * Values are injected by the deployer that packs the gadget.
     */
    WL.StaticAppProps = {
            "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "Cockpit",


"APP_ID": "Cockpit",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "http:\/\/192.168.99.11:10080\/CockpitProj\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "1.2.1",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "windows8",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.1.0.00.20131219-1900",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "http:\/\/192.168.99.11:10080\/CockpitProj\/apps\/services\/api\/Cockpit\/windows8\/"
};</script>
        <script src="worklight/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="worklight/wljq.js"></script>
        <script src="worklight/worklight.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loadingSpinner bigLoad" id="appLoadingIndicator"></div>
        <script src="js/initOptions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/sencha-touch-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I run this code, I get an exception:

> Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic
>   content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be
>   unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or
>   malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML
>   method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and
>   attributes with a method such as createElement. For more information,
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

This can be solved by every sencha call inside the sencha-touch-all into a

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {}
```

This can only be a workaround, as there are too many of these sencha calls.

What is the general concept of using Sencha for Windows Phone, like 
[these steps from Phonegap:](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html)

Comment: Your linking to the Cordova page doesn't make sense. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Also your code snippet does not show actual code containing Sencha Touch functions; it is just part of the generated HTML page of your Worklight-based WP8 app.. doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

IMO there is no good way around it in Windows Phone development. Doesn't matter if it is a pure Cordova app, or a Worklight-based app.

See the second option in the following discussion. Perhaps you could set it in a way that it will work for all code parts required by your app:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e35017b4-e21b-4807-8668-fc3c332c6b32/javascript-runtime-error

Copy-paste:

> The host enforcement code will throw an access denied exception in the
>   event that you try to set the innerHTML (and outerHTML and a couple of
>   others) of an element to HTML which doesn't conform to a whitelist of
>   known safe HTML. You can get around this in a couple of ways:
>
> 1. call `toStaticHTML()` on your string first which should strip out everything which is disallowed
> 2. **use `WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe(element, text)`, this allows you to set innerHTML to anything you like**
> 3. use `msWWA.execUnsafeLocalFunction`, for instance:
>
>    msWWA.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () { element.innerHTML = text; })
>
> Option 2 is implemented in terms of 3. Be aware that if you set
>   innerHTML of an element to html that you don't control (e.g. something
>   you downloaded off the web like an RSS feed) it may contain script
>   which will be able to access the WinRT and do bad things which is why
>   the names of the functions in 2) and 3) are purposefully a little
>   scary.